# How to get syn and syn+ack time use gopacket within connection?

Tags: go, gopacket

I want to obtain the latency between **syn** and **syn+ack** for a connection.

Example:

1. syn and syn+ack latency
2. syn+ack and ack latency

http get and http resp latency

```
client     sniffer   server
syn ------------------->
 
  <---------------------syn+ack
       syn+ack time - syn time = server latency

 ack-------------------->
       ack time - syn+ack = client latency

  http get------------->

 ---------------------->http resp
      http resp time - http get time = http server latency
```

How can I do this with **gopacket tcp stream Reassembly** ?